# Using Swift Package Manager with version control

Tags: svn, swift-package-manager, modularization

I am trying to break down my existing code into separate repos and integrate each repo through Swift Package Manager in the base codebase.

I have used SPM to achieve the same for the repos hosted on git servers, but for some reasons in this case we have to host and integrate repos using SVN.

When I try to add a package hosted in SVN through Xcode it always throws alert with request to enter credentials:

'The remote repository could not be accessed.'

Make sure a valid repository exists at the specified location and the correct credentials have been supplied.

Login: Username and Password

UserName: **Entered correct user name**

Password: **Entered correct password**

I was connected to VPN while trying so.

Am I missing anything over here?

Comment: What's in the SVN server's logs?

Comment: And does it work when you run `svn info <REPO-URL>` with the same credentials?

Comment: Correct .. I am able to download it through separate tools such as SVNx.

Answer (score 0):

Swift Package Manager must be hosted with git, though I read Apple are going to support other sources soon. See more here:
https://forums.swift.org/t/using-swift-package-manager-with-version-control/61738

Comment: that thread was started by me. There is no such comment about them supporting other sources. They have no plans to support SVN. I am not surprised as Xcode too does not provide support for SVN.